# Zip a folder without hidden files or directories

Tags: windows, zip

As part of our work, we need to zip a bunch of folders and documents together and send them somewhere else, this is done with windows built in send to > compressed folder.

Recently we have received complaints about "extranous files" which turned out to be hidden files created by words autosave feature which were included in the zip file.

My question is, is there a way to tell windows built-in zip feature to ignore hidden files and folders? Or are there tools that support such a switch?

Comment: How are you currently doing the zip? Drag-and-drop? Batch file? PowerShell script?

Comment: The simple right click > send to > compressed folder

Comment: So you're selecting all files in the folder and then doing the SendTo? If so, you undoubtedly have the folder set to show hidden files; turn that off. Alternatively, write a PowerShell script to do the zipping (I'm assuming that you're on Windows 10, and thus have Windows PowerShell 5 or later).

Comment: Show hidden files is turned off, still happening.

Comment: Does it happen if you select only some of the files in the folder, or only when you select all the files using `Ctrl`-`A`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41081488/how-do-i-exclude-a-folder-in-compress-archive
you need to use powershell or a script to do this, right clicking on the folder and clicking send to compressed is going to include all files in that folder whether show hidden files is on or off.